# Closing an overlay with an a href

Tags: javascript

I have a navigation overlay and what I would like to do is close the navigation when a link is clicked. It works with `href="#"` but my links are `href="someplace.com"`. How can I have the link close my div while still using the href?

```
`<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".menu-wrapper a").click(function(){
 $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
 $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
 });
 });
 $('.overlay').on('click', function(){
 $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
 $(".menu-wrapper a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
 open = false;
 });
 </script>`
```

and the link is

```
`<li><a class="btn-close" href="<?php echo SITE_URL;    ?>profiles">Profiles</a></li>`
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If the link has href="#" page doesn't get reloaded, otherwise it would.
You could do this:

```
<li><a class="btn-close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeOverlay()">Profiles</a></li>
```

then write a function

```
function closeOverlay() {...}
```

where you would close the overlay and call AJAX to get your PHP data

Answer (score 0):

My Jquery is rusty

```
$('.some-class-for-all-nav-links').click(function () {
// select the nav and close it with css or javascript
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Events in a browser cascade down and then up. Say you have the following structure:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <p>Here is a <a href="#sample">link</a></p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you click on the link, the `click` event is sent to any event listener bound to elements in this order: `window, html, body, section, p, a, a, p, section, body, html, window`. Whether an event occurs when the event is passing from top to bottom (on capture) or from bottom to top (on bubbling) is determined by setting the `onCapture` boolean parameter on the `addEventListener` call.

You could bind an event to the HTML document that is triggered on capture, checks if the user clicked a link and if so, close the nav or whatever it is you want to do. I don't think jquery supports event capturing, you'll have to do it vanilla-style.

Here's some JS following my mockup example. This adds an event listener to the whole document which will fire when a click is detected. It then checks that the thing that was clicked is actually a link (`<a>` element).

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    alert("You've just clicked a link");
  }
}, true); // true to trigger on 'capture'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gf9drum2/

Comment: I thank you for your feedback, however I don't have the jquery skills needed to implement what you are suggesting. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @NickGalgay It's not jquery, but vanilla JS you need. I'll edit the answer with actual code since I'm in a good mood :)